# WooCommerce - custom checkout fields - missing in my-account and emails?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have followed this documentation over at woocommerce on how to customise checkout fields:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

OK, so now I have some custom fields on my checkout page (like gender, title,...). But they are missing on all emails that get sent out by woocommerce and in the user account they are missing too. Actually I can't find them anywhere in WordPress backend (orders, users,...). Where do those fields get stored?

How can I add those additional fields everywhere?